# Can't access packages in my project

Tags: java, package

we (my project group and me) try to access different packages within our working directory.
As you may notice we are actually playing around with those nasty Robots... ;)

Our main is in the class located called RobotWars.java.

Example code from this class:

```
import becker.robots.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import WarRobots.*;
import Listeners.*;
```

In each of the classes we have in those packages we wrote package and the package name for example in SetSpeedListener.java:

```
package Listeners;
```

But when we try to compile we get some annoying errors like:

```
RobotWars.java:10: error: package WarRobots does not exist
import WarRobots.*;
^
RobotWars.java:11: error: package Listeners does not exist
import Listeners.*;
^
```

But we did write the package thing in the beginning of each class... So what are we doing wrong?

```
   .
    ├── Listeners
    │   ├── PauseResumeListener.java
    │   └── SetSpeedListener.java
    ├── RobotWars.java
    ├── WarRobots
        ├── RandomRobot.java
        └── WarRobot.java
```

Our folder structure is the one above.

Thx for help
//Jonas

Comment: First thing to do: stop using unconventional package names. You should work out a "root" package, and make sure all your package names are lower case. It's also not clear how you're compiling, which is important.

Comment: What is above Listeners and WarRobots ? In java relative import are not permitted.

Comment: We are compiling with javac RobotWars.java beckers robot lib is in my classpath.

Comment: Is `WarRobot.java` already compiled?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an IDE like Eclipse? It just makes life a lot easier. An IDE will help in importing the classes you need (if they are indeed available)

Comment: This error comes when we are compiling.

Comment: Yes we are using Eclipse - but this project is on git - so we have to compile it manually in the commandline...